# A good (and preferably fast) way to format IUPAC nomenclature in Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a large data set that contains a number of IUPAC organic chemical nomenclature formatted like this:

`2_3_7_8_TETRACHLORODIBENZO_P_DIOXIN_EXPOSURE`

I would need to be able to translate this to the standard IUPAC form, to wit:

`2,3,7,8-tetrachlorodibenzo-p-dioxin exposure`

There is a limited list of what single characters would be part of the chemical name (e.g. `P` in the above case) and in any case that isn't, `_` would be replaced by `[blank space]`. However, what I'm struggling with is to differentiate in regex the cases where `_` is replaced by `-` and where it's replaced by `,`. I'm using regex replacements with named regexes and a function to replace them. The capture regex for locants is

`(?P<locants>((^|\s)\d{1,2}\s){1,6})` (note that in this case, `_`s have already been replaced by blank spaces, hence the prevalence of `\s` rather than `_`)

But how do I go about writing something to make sure that the space after 2, 3 and 7 is replaced by `,` but the one after 8 is replaced by `-`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the lookahead feature to select the dashes followed by digits:

```
s = "2_3_7_8_TETRACHLORODIBENZO_P_DIOXIN_EXPOSURE"
s = re.sub(r"_(?=\d)", "," ,s)
#'2,3,7,8_TETRACHLORODIBENZO_P_DIOXIN_EXPOSURE'
s = re.sub(r"_", "-" ,s)
#'2,3,7,8-TETRACHLORODIBENZO-P-DIOXIN-EXPOSURE'
```

(You still have to do the locants, but it looks like you already know how to handle them.)